# Show that the path integral of the pullback of a 1-form is equal to the integral of the 1-form over the transformation image of the curve

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-writing, differential-forms, greens-theorem, exterior-derivative

This is from Edwards's Advanced Calculus of Several Variables, Exercise V2.15, page 321.

> Let $\omega$ be a continuous 1-form and $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}^{2}$
>   be $\mathscr{C}^{1}.$ Show that
>
> $$
> \int_{\gamma}F^{\ast}\omega=\int_{F\circ\gamma}\omega.
> $$

Based on discussions elsewhere in the text, I assume $F:\mathbb{R}_{uv}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}_{xy}^{2}$
is sufficiently well-behaved. So it is reasonable to write our 1-form
as

$$
\omega=\mathcal{P}\mathbf{d}x+\mathcal{Q}\mathbf{d}y,
$$

where $\mathcal{P},\mathcal{Q}:\mathbb{R}_{xy}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}.$
The pullback reparameterizes $\mathcal{P},\mathcal{Q}$ such that
$F^{\ast}\mathcal{P},F^{\ast}\mathcal{Q}:\mathbb{R}_{uv}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}.$
It also rewrites $\mathbf{d}x,\mathbf{d}y$ so that they take vectors
in $\mathbb{R}_{uv}^{2}$ as arguments. That is

$$
F^{\ast}\mathbf{d}x=\left(\frac{\partial\mathit{x}}{\partial u}\mathbf{d}u+\frac{\partial\mathit{x}}{\partial v}\mathbf{d}v\right),
$$

$$
F^{\ast}\mathbf{d}y=\left(\frac{\partial\mathit{y}}{\partial u}\mathbf{d}u+\frac{\partial\mathit{y}}{\partial v}\mathbf{d}v\right).
$$

So that the pullback of $\omega$ is

$$
F^{\ast}\omega=\mathcal{P}\circ F\left(\frac{\partial\mathit{x}}{\partial u}\mathbf{d}u+\frac{\partial\mathit{x}}{\partial v}\mathbf{d}v\right)+\mathcal{Q}\circ F\left(\frac{\partial\mathit{y}}{\partial u}\mathbf{d}u+\frac{\partial\mathit{y}}{\partial v}\mathbf{d}v\right)
$$

From this it is intuitively obvious that the assertion of the exercise
holds. That is, at every point along the path $\gamma$ the components of the 1-form $\omega$ are evaluated using the image $F\left(\gamma\left(t\right)\right)$, and $\omega$ operates on the image of the velocity vector, which is the velocity vector of the image curve.

But I'm not sure how to state this in a rigorous way.

The definition Edwards gives for the path integral of a 1-form is

$$
\int_{\gamma}\omega=\int_{a}^{b}\omega_{\gamma\left(t\right)}\left(\gamma^{\prime}\left(t\right)\right)dt.
$$

The only thing that comes to mind is appeal to the Riemann sum definition
of the integral.

**How might the assertion of the exercise be demonstrated rigorously?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is better to do this using the general definitions, of the line integral and pullback.  Going to coordinates clutters everything up.

$\int_{\gamma}\omega:=\int_{a}^{b}\omega_{\gamma\left(t\right)}\left(\gamma^{\prime}\left(t\right)\right)dt=\int_{[a,b]}\gamma^*\omega\Rightarrow \int_{F\circ\gamma}\omega=\int_{[a,b]}(F\circ \gamma)^* \omega=\int_{[a,b]}\gamma^*F^* \omega=\int_{\gamma}F^*\omega.$

To do the calculation rigorously from scratch, (with the understanding that I do not know how Edwards introduces these ideas) note that

$1).\ \gamma'(t_0)$ operates on smooth functions $f$ as follows: $\gamma'(t_0)f:=\left(\frac{df\circ \gamma(t)}{dt}\right )\big |_{t=t_0}$. So to distinguish the operator from the ordinary derivative, we write the latter with a dot above the functional symbol. So, $\overset{.}{\gamma}(t)$ means the ordinary derivative of $\gamma$ at $t$.

$2).\ $ The symbol $x$ is the $\textit{function}:(x,y)\mapsto x$. That is, the projection onto the first coordinate. Similarly for $y$.

$3).\ $ We have $\gamma(t)=(\gamma^1(t),\gamma^2(t))=(x,y)$ and the differentials $dx$ and $dy$ operate on $\gamma'(t)$ as follows: $dx(\gamma'(t))=x\circ \gamma(t)=\gamma^1(t)$ and similarly for $dy$.

$4).\ $ the action of $F^*$ on $\omega$ will be clear in what follows.

To start the calculation, we have $\omega_{\gamma(t)}=P(\gamma(t))dx+Q(\gamma(t))dy.$ Now

$F^*\omega_{\gamma(t)}=P(F\circ\gamma(t))d(x\circ F)+Q(F\circ\gamma(t))d(y\circ F)=$

$P(F\circ\gamma(t))dF^1+Q(F\circ\gamma(t))dF^2$  so

$F^*\omega_{\gamma(t)}(\gamma'(t))=P(F\circ\gamma(t))dF^1(\gamma'(t))+Q(F\circ\gamma(t))dF^2(\gamma'(t))=$

$P(F\circ\gamma(t))\overset{.}{(F\circ\gamma})^1(t)+Q(F\circ\gamma(t))\overset{.}{(F\circ\gamma)^2}(t))$ so

> $\int_{\gamma}F^*\omega=\int_{a}^{b}F^*\omega_{\gamma\left(t\right)}\left(\gamma^{\prime}\left(t\right)\right)dt=\int_{a}^{b}P(F\circ\gamma(t))\overset{.}{(F\circ\gamma}^1)(t)+Q(F\circ\gamma(t))\overset{.}{(F\circ\gamma)^2}(t))dt$

On the other hand,

$\omega_{F\circ\gamma(t)}(F\circ\gamma)'(t)=P(F\circ\gamma(t))dx(F\circ\gamma)'(t)+Q(F\circ\gamma(t))dy(F\circ\gamma)'(t)=$

$P(F\circ\gamma(t))(F\circ\gamma)'(t)x+Q(F\circ\gamma(t))(F\circ\gamma)'(t))y=$

$P(F\circ\gamma(t))(\overset{.}{F\circ\gamma)}^1(t)+Q(F\circ\gamma(t))(\overset{.}{F\circ\gamma)}^2(t))$

so

> $\int_{F\circ\gamma}\omega=\int_{a}^{b}\omega_{F\circ\gamma\left(t\right)}\left(F\circ\gamma)^{\prime}\left(t\right)\right)dt=\int_{a}^{b}(P(F\circ\gamma(t))(\overset{.}{F\circ\gamma)}^1(t)+Q(F\circ\gamma(t))(\overset{.}{F\circ\gamma)}^2(t)))dt.$

The items in blockquotes are equal, which finishes the proof.

Comment: The reason I wrote things out in component form is because that's the way Edwards defined them.  Your proof appears valid assuming a more abstract and useful definition of *pullback* has been introduced.  I know he revisits the subject later, in the chapter on differential forms, but at this point in the book, his definitions are pretty much ad hoc rules for symbol manipulation.  If you have the time and inclination, it would add a lot to your answers if you were to include the definition of *pullback* upon which your proof rests.

Comment: I have added to my answer. If you have different definitions, let me know and I will try to do the calculation using them.

Comment: It may surprise you to learn that Edwards never discusses cotangent spaces, and only mentions a dual vector space once, and that is in an exercise.  I find that only a bit surprising, since I have seen this field of mathematics treated in numerous very different ways.  I skimmed the first 25 pages of Warner's Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds, and Lie Groups yesterday, and found that he treats virtually every topic with which I am familiar in an unrecognizable way.

Comment: For Edwards, $\mathbf{d}x$ is the projection operator which gives the magnitude of the projection of a vector in the $x$ direction.  The middle expression in your last equation is the trick I was missing.

Comment: Yes, I see. Which is exactly what the projection $(x,y)\mapsto x$ does.  I have been self-studying diff geometry myself, and I found [Loring Tu's book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441973993) a great help.

Comment: Ah, now I understand the evidence of sanity, such as distinguishing between a vector and a vector as an operator.  The problem with genuine autodidaction is that the professors are typically very demanding of their students, and are usually teaching at the very edge of our competence.

Comment: Reviewing my notes, I discovered that I had attempted an approach very similar to yours, but failed to carry it through because Edwards has a very confusing way of dealing with the relation $f^\prime\left(t\right)dt=df_t$.  He generally sneers at integrands of the form on the left, but then says, you just call $dt$ an identity mapping, then the equation becomes valid.  This is why I used $\mathbf{d}x,$ etc., when I intended it to be a basis 1-form, rather than the forbidden infinitesimal.  I will note that Schutz explicitly employs both in the second edition of his General Relativity book.

Comment: Yes, $dt$ is the identity because the projection of $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ is $t\mapsto t$. I never really understood these ideas until I saw them related to the tangent and cotangent spaces of a manifold. And I often find the physicists' notation utterly incomprehensible. But Tu does a very good job here in the book I cited above. It has a lot of examples and careful proofs. I am almost done with Lee's Intro to Smooth Manifolds, which is a gem, but does leave a good bit of the verifications to the reader.

Comment: In general, I find that the proofs in diff geometry (which is not my specialty but which I am finding very interesting) assume that one knows quite a few "identifications", and so at first reading, it appears that there is a lot of hand-waving. But in my case at least, I think it's because of my lack of mathematical sophistication. Sigh.

Comment: I'm getting overflow warnings, so this will be my last comment.  What's confusing to me about $dt$ being an identity mapping is what it's actually identifying when it appears in the integrand.  It is simply not true that the "bad old way" of integrating lacks rigior, and implies division by zero, etc.  See the 1958 edition of Thomas's Calculus, or for a genuinely heretical development, see Blandford and Thorne's Modern Claccical Physics.  The same Thorne who coauthered Gravitation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short proof of the statement up top:

**Theorem:** Let $F:M \to N$ be smooth and $\gamma:[a,b] \to M$ a smooth curve segment. If $\omega$ is a smooth cotangent vector field on $N$, prove
$$\int_\gamma F^* \omega = \int_{F \circ \gamma} \omega.$$
**Proof:**
Note we have,
\begin{align*}
    \int_{F \circ \gamma} \omega&=\int_{[a,b]} (F \circ  \gamma)^* \omega && \text{definition}\\
    &=\int_{[a,b]} \gamma^* F^* \omega && \text{property of $*$}\\
    &=\int_\gamma F^* \omega && \text{definition}
\end{align*}
as needed.
$\blacksquare$