# Examples of conservative vector fields in the plane whose closed line integral is not zero

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields

In Vector Calculus, the classic example of a conservative (*irrotational* is more appropriate) vector field in $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{(0,0)\}$ whose line integral over a piecewise smooth closed path may not be $0$ is
\begin{align} \tag{1}
    \mathbf F(x,y) = \frac{-y\mathbf i + x\mathbf j}{x^2+y^2}.
\end{align}

I was trying to find other interesting examples of <s>conservative</s> irrotational vector fields $\mathbf F:\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{(0,0)\} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ for which that happens.

The best I could do was
\begin{align} \tag{2}
    \mathbf F(x,y) = \frac{-f'(x)g(y)\mathbf i + f(x)g'(y) \mathbf j}{f(x)^2+g(y)^2},
\end{align}
where $f,g:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are strictly increasing differentiable functions and $f(0)=g(0)=0$ (perhaps we can be more general).

Then, we can show that the line integral of $\mathbf F$ over any positively oriented, piecewise smooth, simple closed curve that surrounds the origin is $2\pi$.

For example, let $f(x)=x$ and $g(y)=y^3$, then we get $\mathbf F(x,y) = \dfrac{-y^3\mathbf i + 3xy^2 \mathbf j}{x^2+y^6}. \tag{3}$

I would like to know if there exist other simple/interesting examples, i.e., other vector fields that are not linear combinations of the one in the format provided above or other trivial extensions.

*Edit:* I have found a more general form:
\begin{align} \tag{4}
    \mathbf F = \frac{g \nabla f - f \nabla g}{f^2+g^2},
\end{align}
where $f,g:\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are differentiable functions that only map to zero (simultaneously) at the origin.

Comment: I once tried the same. See the last bullet point in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4605719/949989) and in particular Ted Shifrin's comments.

Comment: Greetings @kurt-g, thank you for the suggestion! But, I have used equation (13) as a vector field and evaluated numerically the line integral in a closed circumference of radius 1 centered at the origin and it evaluated to 0. Perhaps, I made a mistake.

Comment: Usually the term "conservative" is reserved for vector fields that admit a potential, whereas vector fields $\mathbf F$ (say, defined on $U \subseteq \Bbb R^2$) with $\operatorname{curl} F = 0$ are called *irrotational*, or sometimes *closed*.

Comment: Haven't seen your calculation so cannot comment. The point why (13) fails to be a valid other example is that it cannot be made continuous on all of $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\}\,.$ Only on a domain with "branch cut" because the map $(x,y)\mapsto\theta$ cannot be mad continuous. BTW Matteo's answer below is  a real gem. Have you understood his proof why $X=cX_0+\nabla f\,?$ This finally clears up everything for me.

Comment: I understood that if you sum $\nabla f$ you can get any field that satisfies the conditions I have imposed. But that does not help me to find other simple vector fields that satisfy the imposed conditions. For example, to get $\mathbf F = (-y^3\mathbf i + 3xy^2 \mathbf j)/(x^2+y^6)$ from Eq. (1), we would need to sum $\nabla(\arctan(y^3/x)-\arctan(y/x))$, and the term $-\nabla \arctan(y/x)$ basically subtracts $\frac{-y\mathbf i + x\mathbf j}{x^2+y^2}$ and the term $\nabla\arctan(y^3/x)$ sums $\frac{-y^3\mathbf i + 3xy^2 \mathbf j}{x^2+y^6}$.

Comment: @Travis Willse, indeed irrotational is more appropriate.

Comment: But $ \arctan(\frac{x}{y})$ is not a function on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus 0$.

Comment: That is why I said basically. It is easy to correct $f(x,y)=\arctan(y^3/x)-\arctan(y/x)$ such that it is a function on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$. Obviously you cannot separate the terms, but when you perform the calculation of $\nabla f$ you *basically* do what I said about summing and subtracting a.e.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a bit informal but can be made rigorous using
the pull-back formalism for differential forms.
I also hope that, as Matteo's answer did, that his is a motiation to
study these things further.

- Your setup $f(0)=0,\,g(0)=0$ (and nonzero elsewhere)  leads to a one-form
  $$\tag{1}
  \boldsymbol{\omega}=\frac{(g\,\partial_x f-f\,\partial_x g)\,dx-(f\,\partial_y g-g\,\partial_yf)\,dy}{f^2+g^2}
  $$
  on $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$
  which is dual to your vector field $\mathbf{F}$ from (4) and closed, $d\boldsymbol{\omega}=0\,,$ but not exact.
  Writing
  $$\tag{2}
  \boldsymbol{\omega}=\frac{g\,(\partial_x f\,dx+\partial_y f\,dy)-f(\partial_xg\,dx+\partial_yg\,dy)}{f^2+g^2}
  $$
  and using
  $$\tag{3}
  df=\partial_x f\,dx+\partial_y f\,dy\,,\quad\quad\quad dg=\partial_xg\,dx+\partial_yg\,dy
  $$
  we get
  $$\tag{4}
  \boldsymbol{\omega}=\frac{g\,df-f\,dg}{f^2+g^2}\,.
  $$
  It is now not surprising that $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ is the pull-back of
  the [irrotational vortex](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4605719/949989)
  $$\tag{5}
  \boldsymbol{\omega}_0=\frac{y\,dx-x\,dy}{x^2+y^2}\,
  $$
  under the map $\Phi:(x,y)\mapsto (f,g)$ which keeps the origin fixed
  and therefore maps $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$ to a subset of it.
- In polar coordinates we know that $\boldsymbol{\omega}_0=d\theta$ and the map
  becomes
  $$\tag{6}
  \Phi:(r,\theta)\mapsto (\rho,\varphi)\,,\quad\rho=\sqrt{f^2+g^2}\,,\quad\varphi=\arctan(g/f)\,,\quad f=\rho\cos\varphi\,,\quad g=\rho\sin\varphi\,.
  $$
  It is not surprising that $\boldsymbol{\omega}=d\varphi\,.$ Since
  $d\varphi=\partial_r\varphi\,dr+\partial_\theta\varphi\,d\theta$ we can write
  $$\tag{7}
  \boldsymbol{\omega}=\partial_r\varphi\,dr+\partial_\theta\varphi\,d\theta
  $$
  which is (1) in polar coordinates.
- We know from $\boldsymbol{\omega}_0=d\theta$ that, for a closed curve in $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\}\,,$
  $$\tag{8}
  \int_\gamma\boldsymbol{\omega_0}=2\pi k_0
  $$
  where $k_0$ is the winding number of $\gamma$ around the origin. When $\gamma$ is closed then $\Phi\circ\gamma$ is closed . Therefore, we know
  from $\boldsymbol{\omega}=d\varphi$ that
  $$\tag{9}
  \int_{\Phi\circ\gamma}\boldsymbol{\omega}=2\pi k
  $$
  where $k$ is the winding number of the curve $\Phi\circ\gamma$ around the origin.
  See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3429004/show-that-the-path-integral-of-the-pullback-of-a-1-form-is-equal-to-the-integral).
- Replacing $\Phi\circ\gamma$ by $\gamma$ it follows now that
  $$\tag{10}
  \int_{\color{red}{\gamma}}\boldsymbol{\omega}=2\pi k_{\color{red}{0}}
  $$
  that is: for any closed curve $\gamma$ the integral of $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ is identcial to that of the irrotational vortex $\boldsymbol{\omega}_0\,.$
  In other words, in that example, Matteo's constant $c$ is one.
- Since for any closed curve in $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$ the integral of $\boldsymbol{\omega}-\boldsymbol{\omega}_0$ is zero it follows now
  from [de Rham cohomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms) that there
  is a function $h$ defined on all of $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$ such that
  $$\tag{11}\boxed{\phantom{\Big|}
  \boldsymbol{\omega}=\boldsymbol{\omega}_0+dh\,.\quad}
  $$
  That $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ is therefore just a trivial modification of the
  irrotational vortex $\boldsymbol{\omega}_0\,.$

Answer (score 4):

They are substantially all equal to the first example times a constant (call it $X_0$), in particular any conservative vector field $X=cX_0+\nabla f$. Where $c$ is some constant. Observe that the second vector field has a potential, so it has no effect on the computation on closed line integral. This you can prove yourself by making sure that $X $ and $X_0$ are evaluated equally on the same closed loop, by adjusting the constant.

If instead of $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus 0$ you take the plane minus two points you can prove that a generic conservative vector field can be written as $X=c_1\cdot X_1 + c_2 \cdot X_2+ \nabla f$, where $X_1,X_2$ are conservative and "rotate around" one of the two points. This fact greatly generalize in the De Rham Cohomology, which precisely tells you how many hole you have on a space by counting the conservative forms, which do not differ by a potential.

Comment: I understand your point and you are correct. However, summing a $\nabla f$ does not give me a method for finding other interesting vector fields. For example, the $\nabla f$ that goes from Eq. (1) to my example is for $f = \arctan(y^3/x) - \arctan(y/x)$ and this does not help me at all, because it is basically subtracting Eq. (1) and summing mine.

Comment: @P.S.Dester Matteo's point is that *all* smooth vector fields on $\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{{\mathbf 0}\}$ have the form $c {\mathbf F} + \nabla g$, where $\mathbf F$ is your example (1) (sometimes called the "vortex vector field"). In that sense, there are no other interesting examples on that domain.

Comment: I understood that there are no other interesting vector fields in the sense of summing some $\nabla g$ to Eq. (1). However, I did not mean interesting in this sense.
I just wanna exclude simple modifications to Eq. (1) and I also do not want a giant cumbersome expression. For example, Eq. (3) is simple and it is not trivial to see the connection with Eq. (1).