# Does Green's theorem need conditions before usage?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

I want to evaluate $\frac{1}{2\pi}\oint_C\dfrac{-y\,dx+x\,dy}{x^2+y^2}$ clockwise around the square with vertices $(-1,-1)$, $(-1,1)$, $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1).$

Obviously $C$ is closed. So if we use Green's theorem for $\vec{F}=(\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2},\,\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})$, we would have:
$$\frac{\partial{F_2}}{\partial{x}}-\frac{\partial{F_1}}{\partial{y}}$$
$$=\frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}-\frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=0$$
So by Green's theorem, integral should be zero. But if we do the integral on four line segments, we will see that it's equal to $-1$. Why is that and where am  I wrong?

Comment: I think it's because of the singularity at point $(0,0)$.

Comment: Yes. The singularity. This [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4605719/949989)  discusses that interesting but fairly standard example in detail. I have seen it coming up everywhere, even in physics (Dirac monopole, Wu-Yang monopole). And before I forget: [de Rham cohomology](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4720554/949989).

Comment: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem) says the involved functions must be $C^1$.